# Stop execution Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to stop execution if a determinate param is true when I called a function. Is that possible?
The only way I found to do that is returning a boolean in check function and depend of it do a return or not in router.get.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
   check(req, res, true);
   console.log(1);
   res.render('page1', {});
});

function check (req,res,param = false){
   if (param){
    res.render('page2');
    // Stop it here
   }
   else {
     return("hi");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (I assume that function check_param return `true` if your parameter `param` set).

```
router.get('/',[function(req,res,next) {
    if (check_param()) {
        res.render('page2');
    } 
    else {
        next();
    }
},function(req,res) {
    res.render('page1',{});
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware and add param check logic there so that you can use it for multiple routes.

```
router.get('/', check, function(req, res){
   res.render('page1', {});
});

function check (req, res, next){
   if (req.param){
    res.render('page2');
   }
   else {
        next()
   }
}
```